# "My name Pablo it's said" - What is the subject?

Tags: grammar, syntax, subjects

What is the subject in the sentence

> "My name Pablo it's said"

I have a confusion about if this sentence is correct in English and if so what's the subject. How is it analyzed syntactically?

Comment: The subject in "My name is Pablo" is "My name".  "Pablo" would be a subject complement of the predicate "is".  But if you're asking about "It is said my name is Pablo" (perhaps you have amnesia and don't know for sure) the subject is so-called "dummy It", and "said my name is Pablo" is the predicate complement of "is", with "my name is Pablo" being a content-clause complement of "said".  "My name is Pablo, it is said" is an inversion.   Hello, they said.  They said hello.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But the structure of *My name's Pablo, it's said* and *It's said my name is Pablo* is different. In the first, *it's said* is a supplement, but in the second *said* is the main verb in the sentence.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo why dont you post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Now I think that **it is said** is the main clause in both and "my name is Pablo" is the supplement in both cases.

Comment: I will add an answer, but I it is just an opinion.

Comment: I think a comma is missing.

Comment: May be. Not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is bauxite, they concur.
>
> They concur, it is bauxite.

Does the main clause change when the order of the clauses changes?  I don't think so.

The main clause is "they concur".

The supplement content-clause which adds info about their concurring is "It is bauxite".

The subject of the main clause is **they**.

The subject of the content-clause supplement is **it**, with **bauxite** being a subject complement.

> It is said, my name is Pablo.
>
> My name is Pablo, it is said.

The main clause is "it is said".

The supplement content-clause which adds info about what is said is "My name is Pablo".

The subject of the main clause is "it".

The subject of the content-clause supplement is "my name", with "Pablo" being a subject complement.

P.S. This is parataxis. You could flip this analysis and make "It is bauxite" the main clause.

.

Comment: Why the commas in _"They concur, it is bauxite"_ and _"It is said, my name is Pablo."_ ?  It seems like in both cases there could be a _"that"_ inserted [ _It is said **that** my name is Pablo._]  Omitting _that_ sounds fine, but replacing it with a comma doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Commas are an orthographic/typographic convention, and not relevant to the underlying grammatical question of how to understand the clausal relationships.